# Re-open *scratch* buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

If I accidentally closed the *scratch* buffer in Emacs, how do I create a new *scratch* buffer?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

GNU Emacs default bindings:

> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `*scratch*` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or, more verbosely

> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `switch-to-buffer *scratch*` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The `*scratch*` buffer is the buffer selected upon startup, and has the major mode [Lisp Interaction](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Interaction.html).  Note: the mode for the `*scratch*` buffer is controlled by the variable [`initial-major-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Entering-Emacs.html).

In general you can create as many "scratch" buffers as you want, and name them however you choose.

> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `NAME` <kbd>RET</kbd>

switches to a buffer `NAME`, creating it if it doesn't exist. A new buffer is not associated with a file on disk until you use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `write-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>) to choose a file where it should be saved.

> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `text-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

changes the current buffer's major mode to Text mode.  To find all the modes available (that is, without requiring any new packages), you can get a list by typing:

> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-command -mode$` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Note that there is something special about *scratch*, at least in GNU Emacs 21 and later: switching to a new *scratch* buffer will put it back into Lisp Interaction mode.

Comment: Just as a quick follow up to this, if your `.emacs` defines a different default *scratch* mode, this one will be the mode for the new *scratch* - not List Interaction mode.

Answer (score 23):

I add following in my .emacs:

```lisp
;; bury *scratch* buffer instead of kill it
(defadvice kill-buffer (around kill-buffer-around-advice activate)
  (let ((buffer-to-kill (ad-get-arg 0)))
    (if (equal buffer-to-kill "*scratch*")
        (bury-buffer)
      ad-do-it)))
```

If I don't want to see *scratch* buffer I press C-x C-k , but it doesn't kill it, just place in the end of buffer list, so then I need it next time I don't have to create new one.

Comment: When I try this advice from "ibuffer", the advice is ignored.  But as best I can tell, "ibuffer" is using "kill-buffer".  Can you help me?

Comment: Well, hitting "close buffer" in the graphical interface *scratch* is deleted.  This works for C-x k only,

Answer (score 15):

There are a whole bunch of tips on [this EmacsWiki page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/RecreateScratchBuffer).

Here's the first one:

> A very simple function to recreate the scratch buffer:

```lisp
(defun create-scratch-buffer nil
   "create a scratch buffer"
   (interactive)
   (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))
   (lisp-interaction-mode))
```

Answer (score 9):

C-x b `*scratch*` RET y RET with iswitchb-mode enabled.

Just C-x b `*scratch*` RET otherwise.

Comment: With default bindings, the 'y RET' is not needed and just inserts a 'y' and a newline into the newly created *scratch* buffer.

Comment: Ooops, maybe that's from iswitchb-mode. Sorry about that. On another topic, try out iswitchb-mode ;)

Comment: One should not, also, there's nothing special about the name *scratch*. One can use C-x b to create any number of "scratch" buffers, with arbitrary names.

Comment: There *is* something special about the name \*scratch\* (as noted in the accepted answer) -- if you create a buffer called \*scratch\* the major mode will be set according to the `initial-major-mode` variable (lisp-interaction-mode by default).

Answer (score 4):

I found this years ago when I first started using emacs; I have no idea where now but it has always had a home in my personal .el files.  It does pop up in google searches.

```lisp
;;; Prevent killing the *scratch* buffer -- source forgotten
;;;----------------------------------------------------------------------
;;; Make the *scratch* buffer behave like "The thing your aunt gave you,
;;; which you don't know what is."
(save-excursion
  (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))
  (make-local-variable 'kill-buffer-query-functions)
  (add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'kill-scratch-buffer))

(defun kill-scratch-buffer ()
  ;; The next line is just in case someone calls this manually
  (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))

  ;; Kill the current (*scratch*) buffer
  (remove-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'kill-scratch-buffer)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer))

  ;; Make a brand new *scratch* buffer
  (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))
  (lisp-interaction-mode)
  (make-local-variable 'kill-buffer-query-functions)
  (add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'kill-scratch-buffer)

  ;; Since we killed it, don't let caller do that.
  nil)
;;;----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to use dwj's solution, and I was quite happy about it, until the day I realized that it failed when you actually *rename* the scratch buffer (for example by saving it).

Then I adopted this, which works well for me :

```lisp
  (run-with-idle-timer 1 t
    '(lambda () (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Like the docstring says, this function will:

> Switch to the scratch buffer. If the buffer doesn't exist create it and write the initial message into it."

This will bring a new scratch buffer up which looks like the initial scratch buffer.

```lisp
(defun switch-buffer-scratch ()
  "Switch to the scratch buffer. If the buffer doesn't exist,
create it and write the initial message into it."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((scratch-buffer-name "*scratch*")
         (scratch-buffer (get-buffer scratch-buffer-name)))
    (unless scratch-buffer
      (setq scratch-buffer (get-buffer-create scratch-buffer-name))
      (with-current-buffer scratch-buffer
        (lisp-interaction-mode)
        (insert initial-scratch-message)))
    (switch-to-buffer scratch-buffer)))

(global-set-key "\C-cbs" 'switch-buffer-scratch)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have `scratch` as an interactive command for opening a new scratch buffer (I like to have several):

```lisp
(defun scratch ()
  "create a new scratch buffer to work in. (could be *scratch* - *scratchX*)"
  (interactive)
  (let ((n 0)
        bufname)
    (while (progn
             (setq bufname (concat "*scratch"
                                   (if (= n 0) "" (int-to-string n))
                                   "*"))
             (setq n (1+ n))
             (get-buffer bufname)))
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create bufname))
  (if (= n 1) initial-major-mode))) ; 1, because n was incremented
```

adopted from: http://everything2.com/index.pl?node_id=1038451

Comment: How is this superior to simply switching to a new buffer (C-x b `bufname` RET)?

Comment: @bignose: I use `ido-mode` and usually have quite a few buffers open.  Creating a new buffer using `C-x b` would be really tedious.  I would have to come up with a unique name that doesn't match any of the currently present buffers.

Answer (score 3):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-z")
                '(lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")))
```

This will not only quickly switch to `*scratch*` buffer(since I do this frequently), but recreate a `*scratch*` buffer and enable `lisp-interaction-mode` automatically if you kill it accidentally. Change the binding as you like.

Answer (score 3):

Just to note emacs package `unkillable-scratch` in MELPA will do this. There is also `scratch-persist` that will automatically save and restore the buffer between sessions.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use - I have this bound to a convenient keystroke. It sends you to the `*scratch*` buffer, regardless of whether or not it already exists, and sets it to be in `lisp-interaction-mode`

```lisp
(defun eme-goto-scratch () 
  "this sends you to the scratch buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let ((eme-scratch-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")))
    (switch-to-buffer eme-scratch-buffer)
    (lisp-interaction-mode)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to have my scratch buffer be an actual file that is automatically saved, and reopening it is as simple as opening a file.  On startup, I kill the default and find my own like this.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    (find-file "/Users/HOME/Desktop/.scratch")))
```

I have a custom kill-buffer function that does essentially the same thing -- reopens my personal scratch saved file and kills the default scratch *if* I killed the last visible buffer.

I customized a few of the `desktop.el` functions to load *after* `(kill-buffer "*scratch*")` and `(find-file "/Users/HOME/Desktop/.scratch")` so that the file last visible on exiting Emacs doesn't get buried by the default scratch or buried by my custom scratch when launching Emacs.

I enjoy using `auto-save-buffers-enhanced`, which automatically saves any file extension that is not specifically excluded:

https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced/blob/master/auto-save-buffers-enhanced.el

```
(require 'auto-save-buffers-enhanced)
(auto-save-buffers-enhanced t)
(setq auto-save-buffers-enhanced-save-scratch-buffer-to-file-p 1)
(setq auto-save-buffers-enhanced-exclude-regexps '("\\.txt" "\\.el" "\\.tex"))
```

I use a slight variation of the function by @paprika when I want to create a no-file visiting buffer:

```
(defun lawlist-new-buffer ()
  "Create a new buffer -- \*lawlist\*"
(interactive)
  (let* (
    (n 0)
    bufname)
  (catch 'done
    (while t
      (setq bufname (concat "*lawlist"
        (if (= n 0) "" (int-to-string n))
          "*"))
      (setq n (1+ n))
      (if (not (get-buffer bufname))
        (throw 'done nil)) ))
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create bufname))
  (text-mode) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have combined the solutions posted so far into one function:

```lisp
(defun --scratch-buffer(&optional reset)
  "Get the *scratch* buffer object.
Make new scratch buffer unless it exists. 
If RESET is non-nil arrange it that it can't be killed."
  (let ((R (get-buffer "*scratch*")))
    (unless R
      (message "Creating new *scratch* buffer")
      (setq R (get-buffer-create "*scratch*") reset t))
        (when reset
          (save-excursion
            (set-buffer R)
            (lisp-interaction-mode)
            (make-local-variable 'kill-buffer-query-functions)
            (add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions '(lambda()(bury-buffer) nil)
          )))
    R))
```

To apply this function in your *.emacs* use:

```lisp
(--scratch-buffer t)
(run-with-idle-timer 3 t '--scratch-buffer)
```

This will make the scratch buffer indestructible in the first place, and if saved it will be recreated. Additionally we can use a shortcut function `scratch` to bring up the buffer quickly:

```lisp
(defun scratch()
  "Switch to *scratch*.  With prefix-arg delete its contents."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (--scratch-buffer))
  (if current-prefix-arg
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (goto-char (point-max))))
```

In the past it has proven useful to know the original startup-directory from which Emacs was started.  This is either the value of `desktop-dirname` or the `default-directory` local variable of the scratch-buffer:

```lisp
(defvar --scratch-directory
  (save-excursion (set-buffer "*scratch*") default-directory)
  "The `default-directory' local variable of the *scratch* buffer.")

(defconst --no-desktop (member "--no-desktop" command-line-args)
  "True when no desktop file is loaded (--no-desktop command-line switch set).")

(defun --startup-directory ()
  "Return directory from which Emacs was started: `desktop-dirname' or the `--scratch-directory'.
Note also `default-minibuffer-frame'."
  (if (and (not --no-desktop) desktop-dirname) 
      desktop-dirname
    --scratch-directory))
```

So *--startup-directory* will always return the base directory of your makefile, TODO-file etc. In case there is no desktop (*--no-desktop* commandline-switch or no desktop-file) the `--scratch-directory` variable will hold directory Emacs was once started under.

Answer (score 1):

find answer in EmacsWiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecreateScratchBuffer

```
(defun create-scratch-buffer nil
   "create a scratch buffer"
   (interactive)
   (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))
   (lisp-interaction-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, if you have ILO mode on (and it is autocompleting after <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>, thus not letting you write `*scratch*`), then try:

> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>C-b</kbd>`*scratch*` <kbd>RET</kbd>

`C-x b C-b *scratch* RET`

Answer (score -3):

> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>  and then type `*scratch*` <kbd>↩︎</kbd>

to create a new buffer which is in lisp interaction mode also.