# In Emacs, what's the canonical way to protect vital buffers like *scratch* and *Messages* from ever being killed?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234963/re-open-scratch-buffer-in-emacs) and the answers are a [convoluted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234963/re-open-scratch-buffer-in-emacs/235186#235186) [mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234963/re-open-scratch-buffer-in-emacs/1042839#1042839) (timer function REALLY?)

In any case, I don't care about recreating these buffers, as that is trivial.  But these buffers contain information which should never be deleted, and because they don't have associated filenames, they are usually killed without confirmation.

I do have a solution in mind, but I want to see if someone has a more "canonical" one.

---

---

*jtahlborn* provided the most canonical solution, except the "keep-buffers" package is showing its age has some issues:

1. You had to specify whether all protected buffers are to be buried and erased (erased buffers can be recovered with `undo') when killed, or just buried when killed.
2. `member` is reimplemented as `find-in-list` less efficiently.
3. Helper functions that didn't really help.

I made the the `protected-list` an alist that associates regexp to erase-action, and deleted the useless (IMO) code.  By default, "*scratch*" is erased when killed, "*Messages*" is never erased or killed.

See [github](https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_libs/blob/master/keep-buffers.el)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use the [keep-buffers](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/gnu/emacs-lisp/incoming/keep-buffers.el) utility.

Comment: See my comments in question.  This package is on the right track, but needs some work.

Comment: @event_jr - cool, you might want to post your updated code on EmacsWiki, that's usually the first place i look for utilities (and this code isn't there currently).

Answer (score 8):

You can try adding a function to the `kill-buffer-query-functions` variable that checks the current buffer, if it is *scratch* or *Messages* then return nil. I've never tried this before but it should prevent them from getting killed.

Edit: Here's an example of using `kill-buffer-query-functions` that allows you to protect specific buffers: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/protbuf-by-name.el

Comment: This is what I currently do, but it's just a snippet in my init file.  I wanted to present a more canonical solution people can import easily into their own init files to hopefully combat some of the weirdness I saw around this issue.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said by others --

`*scratch*` is in no way a "vital" buffer. And by default nothing and no one automatically writes anything to `*scratch*` or modifies anything there.

(FWIW, I tend to use an ordinary Emacs-Lisp mode file buffer instead of `*scratch*`.  One reason is that I do typically want to save it at some point.  (Another reason: I prefer that <kbd>C-j</kbd> do what it does in Emacs-Lisp mode. Yes, I could change just that key binding, but instead I keep `*scratch*` for some kinds of interaction, but typically not for a coding sandbox.)

`*Messages*` is a different story.

But how are you accidentally deleting `*Messages*`?  In decades of using Emacs I don't think I've ever accidentally killed `*Messages*`.  What's the scenario to produce the problem you are looking for a solution to?

Comment: Tangentially, regarding scratch buffers as coding sandboxes, here is a handy library for creating a scratch buffer using the current buffer's mode: https://github.com/ieure/scratch-el

Comment: @Drew, I remember killing lots of buffers when I started using Emacs and would occasionally kill Messages and Scratch.  A few times they had useful information.  So I started protecting them.  Honestly, killing these buffers to bury them is engrained to my workflow now, so I do need them protected.

Comment: I agree, @event_jr: one can easily accidentally kill such a buffer. For me, `*Messages*` is more problematic than `*scratch*`, but that's because I typically do not use `*scratch*` much. I do Lisp coding and testing in a `*.el` buffer (not `*scratch*`), and I toss that buffer/file when I'm done with it.