# In GNU Emacs, how to create new empty buffer with one keystroke?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, ido

How do I create a new empty buffer with a single keystroke? I can create a new buffer with `C-x b` and then entering a name. (I use ido-mode, so if I just hit `RET` it opens the most recent buffer.)

I'd like a command to open a new untitled buffer with a single key binding, e.g. `s-t`.

(Similar to the `new-tab` command in Aquamacs.)

Comment: Why not check the definition of `new-tab` in Aquamacs? It's probably compatible.

Comment: Here is a slight variation of the answer below that does not need a global variable:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21071757/2112489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As YoungFrog pointed out, it can be easier to just generate a new buffer (which will get automatically get a number appended to it when it exists):

```
(defun new-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer "buffer"))
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "\s-t") 'new-buffer)
```

Comment: (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer "buffer")) seems easier.